# Magento 2 getQtyBackordered return empty

Tags: magento2, backorder, sales-order-item

I create a magento 2 beforePlace function to make a code get executed before an order is successfully placed, I wanted to retrieve the backorder qty and do some processing

below is the code that I added

/app/code/GShop/Order/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
        <plugin name="Gtrust_Order_Request_Plugin" type="GShop\Order\Plugin\Model\OrderPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

/app/code/GShop/Order/Plugin/Model/OrderPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace GShop\Order\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderPlugin
{
    private $quoteFactory;
    private $customerCustomerFactory;
    protected $_gtrustConHelper;
    private $orderLogger;
    private $jsonSerializer;

    public function __construct(
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerCustomerFactory,
        \GShop\GtrustConnector\Helper\Data $gtrustConHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer,
        \GShop\Product\Helper\Data $productHelper,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        \GShop\Order\Helper\Data $orderHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \GShop\Utils\Helper\Price $priceUtil,
        \GShop\Order\Model\PamGbBankMappingFactory $pamGbMappingFactory,
        \GShop\Order\Model\Logger $orderLogger,
        \GShop\PWP\Helper\Data $pwpHelper,
        \GShop\Order\Model\GshopBackordersFactory $gshopBackordersFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->customerCustomerFactory = $customerCustomerFactory;
        $this->_gtrustConHelper = $gtrustConHelper;
        $this->jsonSerializer  = $jsonSerializer;
        $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->orderHelper = $orderHelper;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_priceUtil = $priceUtil;
        $this->pamGbMappingFactory = $pamGbMappingFactory;
        $this->orderLogger = $orderLogger;
        $this->_pwpHelper = $pwpHelper;
        $this->_gshopBackordersFactory = $gshopBackordersFactory;
    }

    public function beforePlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject)
    {
        $this->orderLogger->debug("------------------ sales_order_place_before Plugin start-----------------");

        $order = $subject;

        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach ($quoteItems as $subitem) {
            $this->orderLogger->debug('Order getQuoteId : '.$order->getQuoteId());
            $this->orderLogger->debug('getQtyBackordered : '.$subitem->getQtyBackordered());
        }

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

As you can see on the code above I have added this code line below to check whether I am able to get the quantity backordered or not

`$this->orderLogger->debug('getQtyBackordered : '.$subitem->getQtyBackordered());`

But the log recorded shows empty value

```
2023-04-13T15:48:16+08:00 DEBUG (7): Order getQuoteId : 9106077
2023-04-13T15:48:16+08:00 DEBUG (7): getQtyBackordered :
```

I already set configuration on the Catalog > Products > product > Advanced Inventory for Backorders to Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer

[image]

[image]

I even try to modify the `qty_backordered` value in `sales_order_item` table to 1 but I don't see any changes, I am not sure actually where `getQuoteId` refers to and where `getQtyBackordered` refers to, I am hoping someone can explain or highlight me on what I miss so that I can understand